# Pythonic way to pass a optional argument to a function: tweepy

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, tweepy

I'm using the following tweepy function:

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#search-tweets

For every request, it may return (or not) a param called next_token, that works like a pagination to start next request from where i stopped.

```py
requests_list = []
tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, 
                                    start_time=start_time, 
                                    end_time=end_time, 
                                    max_results=max_results, 
                                    expansions=expansions,
                                    tweet_fields=tweet_fields,
                                    user_fields=user_fields,
                                    place_fields=place_fields)

requests_list.append(tweets)

while True:

  if 'next_token' in tweets.meta:
    
    tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, 
                                    start_time=start_time, 
                                    end_time=end_time, 
                                    max_results=max_results, 
                                    expansions=expansions,
                                    tweet_fields=tweet_fields,
                                    user_fields=user_fields,
                                    place_fields=place_fields,
                                    next_token = tweets.meta['next_token'])
    requests_list.append(tweets)

  else:
    
    break
```

So, what i did:

- I make a first request outside the loop, 'cause i know that the first request i don't have next_token yet to pass to the function.
- I loop, if next_token is available i pass it through and append to a list the results, if its not available i break the loop.

1. How can i make it better (less code duplicated)?
2. Can i 'merge' the results (the same structure) instead of appending them into a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to pass your arguments, something like this:

```
args = {'query':query,....}
flag = False
while True:
    if (!flag or 'next_token' in tweets.meta):
        if(flag):
            args['next_token'] = tweets.meta['next_token']
        tweets = client.search_all_tweets(**args)
        flag = True
```

Comment: You need to use `or` instead of `||`

Comment: Yea, wasn't paying attention. @ShanavasM

Answer (score 0):

You can use argument unpacking to pass key work arguments to a function.

```
tweets = None # initial case
requests_list = []
next_token = None

while tweets is None or next_token:
    kwargs = {}
    if next_token:
        kwargs['next_token'] = next_token
    tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, 
                                    start_time=start_time, 
                                    end_time=end_time, 
                                    max_results=max_results, 
                                    expansions=expansions,
                                    tweet_fields=tweet_fields,
                                    user_fields=user_fields,
                                    place_fields=place_fields,
                                    **kwargs)
    requests_list.append(tweets)
    next_token = tweets.meta.get('next_token')
```